# Is there a logical function in excel to extract unique text values from a range of similar texts?

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, unique

I am working on a dataset which has data (text) entries captured in different styles like we see in the table below in 1000's of rows:

| **School Name ** |
| --- |
| Abirem school |
| Abirem sec School |
| Abirem Secondary school |
| Abirem second. School |
| Metropolitan elementary |
| Metropolitan Element. |
| Metropolitan ele |

I need help to extract the unique data values within a group of similar entries regardless of the style it was entered. The output I want should look like we see below:

| **School Name ** |
| --- |
| Abirem school |
| Metropolitan elementary |

I have tried using the functions; EXACT, UNIQUE, MATCH and even XLOOKUP (with the wildcard option) but none of them gives me the output I want.

Is there a logical function that can be used?

Answer (score 2):

This will prove to be tricky. Excel would not know wheather or not two different names that look similar are actually meant to be similar. Even for us humans it will become trivial. I mean; would `School1 ABC` be similar to `School1 DEF` or not? Without actually knowing geographical locations about these two schools these could well be two different schools with a similar first word in their names.

Either way, if you happen to be willing to accept this ambiguity you could make a match on the 1st word of each line here and return only those where they match first:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=LET(a,A1:A7,UNIQUE(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(a," ")&" *",a&" ",a,,2)))
```

Comment: Hi Jvdv, yes I have tried the above code and it solves part of the problem. Is it possible to lookup a unique value in a column based on two different columns?

Comment: Offcourse, but that's not your question here right?

Comment: JvdV, like I said, the code:=LET(a,A1:A7,UNIQUE(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(a," ")&" *",a&" ",a,,2))) works but there seems to be a challenge. It picks the item in the first column as the default (in this case, unique) element or name. Is there a way around it?

Comment: If this is a follow-up question it may be better to ask a new question with appropriate sample data and expected results. Helping you out with the current sample data was challenging enough, trying to adjust based on your comments is way harder.